# How to test RxDB in Redux-saga with Jest?

Tags: rxjs, jestjs, redux-saga

I am trying to cover redux-saga that gets data from RxDB with Jest tests.

```
export function* checkUnsavedData(action) {
  const { tab } = action;
  try {
    const db = yield getDB().catch(e => {
      throw new Error(e);
    });

    const currentUser = yield select(makeSelectCurrentUser());

    const unsavedData = yield db[USER_COLLECTION].findOne(currentUser)
      .exec()
      .then(data => data && data.unsavedData)
      .catch(e => {
        throw new Error(e);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    yield showError(error);
  }
}
```

Everything is fine in live run. But testing the generator I get:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Error: RxError:
RxDatabase.create(): Adapter not added. Use RxDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-adapter-[adaptername]');
Given parameters: {
adapter:"idb"}
```

If anyone has done this, please, tell me how to test such cases with RxDB in redux-saga with Jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did non add the adapter to RxDB. Can you paste the code where you create the database? This would help more in finding the error.

When running tests, you should not use the idb-adapter. Use the [in-memory-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-adapter-memory), it's faster and also you can be sure that you start on a clean state on each testrun.